# Ambiguous Grammar demostration exercise

Tags: formal-grammars, ambiguity, tree-grammars

Hi im stuck on an exercise of ambiguous grammar. I need an example that shows that this grammar is ambiguous. The grammar is defined as follows:

$$S \rightarrow aT | bR$$
$$R \rightarrow a | aS | bRR$$
$$T \rightarrow b | bS | aTT$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example is the word $aabbab$.

We can either create it like this
$$S \rightarrow aT \rightarrow aaTT \rightarrow
 aabST \rightarrow aabbRT \rightarrow aabbaT \rightarrow aabbab.$$
Or like this
$$S \rightarrow aT \rightarrow aaTT \rightarrow
aabT \rightarrow aabbS \rightarrow aabbaT \rightarrow aabbab.$$